# How to solve limits for multivariables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve the limit for a multivariable function(three variables) in Python using `sympy` but the limit() method just works with one variable; and, if I try with subs, it works with 2 arguments f(x, y), But I need three arguments f(x, y, z).

Trying with limit() method:

```
from sympy import *
import math
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
exp = limit((x**3 + y*x**2)/sqrt(x**4 + y**2 + z**4), x, 0, y, 0, z, 0)
print(exp)
```

TypeError: limit() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 7 were given

Trying with subs:

```
from sympy import *
import math
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
exp = (x**3 + y*x**2)/sqrt(x**4 + y**2 + z**4)
res_exp = exp.subs([x,0], [y,0], [z,0])
print(res_exp)
```

ValueError: subs accepts either 1 or 2 arguments

Comment: could you please attach your code here because I do not clearly understand what you need exactly even if there is an error on your code?

Comment: thnks, I already attached the code, those are the 2 ways that try evaluate the limit but i get those errors

Comment: It is actually rather hard to prove that a multivariable limit exists in the first place. For example, if you hold x constant at 0 and check the limit as y goes to 0, it may differ from the result of holding y constant and checking as x goes to 0. I think to at least some extent you really have a math question rather than a programming question. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/975799/proving-multivairble-limit-exists .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at like these tasks but I will try helping you:
your error in the first code is:
**TypeError: limit() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 7 were given**
this code is limit() function because this function takes 3 arguments should being found and 1 additional as an optional argument as following:
1- expression – The mathematical expression on which limit operation is to be performed, i. e., f(x).
2- variable – It is the variable in the mathematical expression, i. e., x
3- value – It is the value to which the limit tends to, i. e., a.
Returns: Returns the limit of the mathematical expression under given conditions.

so, what could I do is I'll give you a hint to solve this problem, you can try this code out and go ahead on the same pattern almost.

```
from sympy import *
import math
x, y, z = symbols('x, y, z')
exp = limit((x**3 + y*x**2)/sqrt(x**4 + y**2 + z**4), (x, 0, y, 0, z, 0), 0)
print(exp)
```

be sure you have put 3 or 4 arguments in the last line.
I know this info isn't enough for you but I just try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer, the way that work for me was make a method similar to limit() that accepts 7 arguments and then evaluate the equation when each axis goes to 0. The function receive the equation, and the point to evaluate.

```
from sympy import *
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
exp1 = (3*x*z**2*y + y**2) / (x**2 + 2*y**2 + z**4)
exp2 = (x*y + y*z +x*z) / (x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
exp3 = (x*z**2 + 2*y**2) / (x**2 + 2*y**2 + z**4)

def limit3var(eq, var1, val1,var2, val2, var3, val3):
    res_eqx = eq.subs([(var2, val2), (var3, val3)]) #x goes to 0.
    res_eqy = eq.subs([(var1, val1), (var3, val3)]) #y goes to 0.
    res_eqz = eq.subs([(var1, val1), (var2, val2)]) #z goes to 0.

    print("Evaluate x-axis : {}".format(res_exp))
    print("Evaluate y-axis : {}".format(res_exp2))
    print("Evaluate z-axis : {}".format(res_exp3))

    if res_exp != res_exp2 or res_exp != res_exp3 or res_exp2 != res_exp3:
        print("The limit does not exist in that point: ")
    else:
        print("The function is continuous in that point")
```

Running in console:

```
In[45]: limit3var(exp1, x, 0, y, 0, z, 0)
Evaluate x-axis : 0
Evaluate y-axis : 1/2
Evaluate z-axis : 0
The limit does not exist in that point

In[46]: limit3var(exp2, x, 0, y, 0, z, 0)
Evaluate x-axis : 0
Evaluate y-axis : 0
Evaluate z-axis : 0
The function is continuous

In[47]: limit3var(exp3, x, 0, y, 0, z, 0)
Evaluate x-axis : 0
Evaluate y-axis : 1
Evaluate z-axis : 0
The limit does not exist in that point
```

Answer (score 0):

### **if someone didn't find subs solution**
you can do this by editing your code to be like

```
from sympy import *
import math
x, y, z = symbols('x y z')
exp = (x**3 + y*x**2)/sqrt(x**4 + y**2 + z**4)
# ***
res_exp = exp.subs(x,0).subs(y,0).subs(z,0)
# ***
print(res_exp)
```

---

**and that should work fine for you ...**